# Getting a value from a function in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am a bit new to WordPress and i have a small problem.

I'm checking if my mail was send or not and i want to save this information in a custom table that i made. I need to retrieve this information in a different function where I then save this in my custom table.

This is the function where i check if the mail is send or not.

```
/*
 * Send notification when stock is low
 */

function boilerplate_custom_low_stock_notification( $order ) {

foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
    print_r($item);

    if ( $item->is_type( 'line_item' ) && ( $product = $item->get_product() ) && $product->managing_stock() ) {

        $new_stock = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_stock', true );
        $minimum_stock = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_stock_minimum', true );

        $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();
        $name = $product->get_name();

        if ( $new_stock <= $minimum_stock ) {

            //Send email to admin
            $notification = wp_insert_post(
                array(
                    'post_type'     => 'shop_history',
                    'post_title'    => 'The stock of '. $name . ' is running low.',
                    'post_content'  => 'The stock is running low. There are only ' . $stock . " pieces left.",
                    'post_status'   => 'publish',
                ) );

            $mailResult = false;
            $mailResult = wp_mail( get_option('admin_email'), 'Your stock is running low', 'The stock of ' . $name . ' is running low. You have ' . $stock . ' piece(s) left.' );

            if( $mailResult == true){
                $mail_send = "Mail was send";
            }else{
                $mail_send = "Something went wrong en there was no mail send";
            }
            //error_log( $mail_send );

            return $notification;

            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_reduce_order_stock', 'boilerplate_custom_low_stock_notification', 10, 3 );
```

In this function i want to save the information.

```
/*
 * Add values to column
 */
function woocommerce_shop_history_mail_column( $column, $post_id ) {

    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'mail' :
            echo 'Is my mail send or not?';
            break;
    }
}

add_filter( 'manage_shop_history_posts_custom_column', 'woocommerce_shop_history_mail_column', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: From what I've understoond you need to hook a new order, correct? If yes, you'd need to use the woocommerce_new_order instead of your custom manage_shop_history_posts_custom_column

Comment: No. I made a history tab in the WooCommerce plugin where the admin can see when his stock was running low and if an email was send to him/her or not.

I want to retrieve the **$mail_send** value and use it in my **woocommerce_shop_history_mail_column** function where I then save it in my custom column.